# hasOne and belongsTo relation tables - laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My tables :

```
users :

id fname email

brands:

id title user_id_made
```

each user has many `brand`s and each `brand` belongTo an `user`.

```
class Brand extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'brands';

    protected $fillable = array('title_fa',
        'title_en','logo','user_id_made');



    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\User');
    }
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'fname' ,'lname' , 'username', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Brand','user_id_made');
    }
}
```

my code hasn't any output about users .

```
    $data['brands']         = \DB::table('brands')->find(1);

    var_dump($data['brands']);
    return;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not load user. I will suggest you to use model instance in place of DB instance. if you want to load user with brands then you can use laravel's eager loading.

First in your Brand.php model

> You need to pass the second argument as **user_id_made** to hasOne function otherwise it will assume it user_id.

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\User','user_id_made');
}
```

You can do something like that.

```
$data['brands']  = Brand::with('user')->find(1);
```

Now If you will return $data['brands'] then it will return user information also.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I have a list as brands and inside it I want to show email of user that made that brand.

Comment: yes. now how to get user info ?! `$brand->User->fname` doesn't work.